# Mixing lightweight transactions and normal writes in Cassandra

Tags: transactions, cassandra, compare-and-swap

The [Datastax documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlLtwtTransactions.html) for lightweight transaction states:

*"Lightweight transactions use a timestamping mechanism different than for normal operations and mixing LWTs and normal operations can result in errors. If lightweight transactions are used to write to a row within a partition, only lightweight transactions for both read and write operations should be used."*

This is very vague (BTW what do they even mean by LWTs for read operations?).

Can someone with deeper knowledge of Cassandra internals elaborate on possible problems when mixing LWTs and normal writes?

My best guess is that there might be problems with concurrency (obviously). But I thought that if I (for example) insert a row using `IF NOT EXISTS` and if that was successful I later do `UPDATE` of the same partition, I will be fine. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 8):

I agree that the documentation is not quite accurate on LWT constraints so let me clarify them:

- If you use `INSERT ... IF NOT EXISTS`, **all deletes** should also use `DELETE ... IF EXISTS`
- If you use `UPDATE table SET column1=val1 WHERE <filters> IF column2=val2` then all updates/inserts on column1 & column2 should use LWT too. A common usage is when **column1** and **column2** are the same column.

Indeed LWT has 4 rounds:

1. Propose a Paxos ballot (a timeuuid value) to all replicas of the given partition
2. Check the condition (`IF NOT EXISTS`, `IF EXISTS` or `IF col=val`). If the condition is not met, fail here
3. Else, wait for a **QUORUM**/**LOCAL_QUORUM** to accept the Paxos ballot
4. Commit and apply the mutation (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`)

Step **b** and **c** can be seen as a **Compare And Swap**.

The guarantees are that **all writes** using LWT are **linearizable** with respect to each others, so they are **atomic** and **isolated** on the partition.

Now if you use `INSERT ... IF NOT EXISTS` and then simple `DELETE` without LWT, you defeat the purpose of LWT and the LWT guarantees no longer apply.

Since the Compare phase (step 2) and the Commit phase (step 4) are in different steps, the only way to provide atomicity is to force others mutations to go throught LWT otherwise the logic is broken.

Same remark for the conditional updates with LWT.

Comment: What about the note about LWTs for *reads* on this group of columns in a partition? The idea being that a write won't return results to the client doing the writing until a read would succeed anyway, if a LWT is used. So, that would mean reads using non-LWTs would have no impact on operations occurring during the compare and set phases, right?